# Run Excel macro on multiple workbooks / files

Tags: excel, file, vba

I found this script to loop through workbooks within a folder.

```
Sub OpenFilesVBA()
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim strFil As String

    strFolder = "c:\Temp"
    strFil = Dir(strFolder & "\*.xls*")
    Do While strFil <> vbNullString
        Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(strFolder & "\" & strFil)
        Wb.Close False
        strFil = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

I seved my macro to `PERSONAL.XLSB` which is called "import". My files are Microsoft Excel csv files which will be at the of my code saved as xlsx.

My question is how to modify the above code to run my macro through all the files? where to include my macro?

Many thanks

Comment: Change `strFil = Dir(strFolder & "\*.xls*")` to `strFil = Dir(strFolder & "\*.csv*")`

Comment: where shall I put my macro in this code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do something to the workbook you've opened your code will need to go after the `Workbooks.Open` function:

```
Sub OpenFilesVBA()

Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim strFolder As String
Dim strFil As String

strFolder = "c:\Temp"
strFil = Dir(strFolder & "\*.csv*")
Do While strFil <> vbNullString
    Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(strFolder & "\" & strFil)

    'Add your code here

    Wb.Close False
    strFil = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Do I need to add the whole code or is there a way to provide the macro name or some sort of link ?

Comment: Just use the name of the macro e.g. if your sub is called `import` simply add `import` with whichever parameters you need.